# Lock cursor axis - MacOS

Tags: swift, macos

I was wondering if it is possible to lock the x or y axis of the cursor?

I have been playing around with **CGWarpMouseCursorPosition()** by setting the mouse's x or y position to a certain value inside **mouseMoved()** whenever I want to lock an axis, but that doesn't seem to work.

Thanks!

**Edit:**

If X key pressed:

```
if !xLocked {
    xLocked = true
    xLockPos = view!.window!.mouseLocationOutsideOfEventStream.x 
}
```

If Y key pressed:

```
if !yLocked {
    yLocked = true
    yLockPos = view!.window!.mouseLocationOutsideOfEventStream.y 
}
```

I've tried the following in **update()** and **mouseMoved()**:

```
if xLocked {
    CGWarpMouseCursorPosition(CGPoint(x: xLockPos, y: view!.window!.mouseLocationOutsideOfEventStream.y))
}

if yLocked {
    CGWarpMouseCursorPosition(CGPoint(x: view!.window!.mouseLocationOutsideOfEventStream.x, y: yLockPos))
}
```

Just can't quite figure out where I'm going wrong. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`CGAssociateMouseAndMouseCursorPosition`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1454486-cgassociatemouseandmousecursorpo?language=objc) to disconnect the pointer movement from mouse movement. Then you can use `CGWarpMouseCursorPosition` to move the mouse along only one axis as you receive mouse events.

Comment: Thanks for the help! The only trouble I'm having now is since my application size isn't full screen, when I set a mouse position it moves the mouse to that position if the application were set in the top left corner of my actual screen. Is there a way to get the size and position of my application and take that into account? Thanks again.

Comment: Edit your question to include the code that looks at the event and moves the pointer.

Comment: Edited the question